# Snippet HTML en entrada de Wordpress me genera código extra/basura y duplicado

Tags: html, wordpress, div, flexbox

Buenas.
Estoy intentando hacer un boton con un texto y un icono para descargar un PDF en entradas de Wordpress.

He probado en JSFIDDLE y funciona de maravilla.

```css
#dwnld-pdf {
clear: both;
padding: 0.8% 0;
display: flex;
border: 1.2px solid;
width: 232px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-evenly;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
}

#dwn-img { /* div imagen */
display: flex;
width: 28px;
}
```

```html
<a id="dwnld-pdf" class="clearfix" href="" title="Descarga el archivo archivo" download>
<div id="dwn-img"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-basic-1/57/basic1-046_file_pdf-512.png" alt="Icono de archivo PDF"></div><div>Descarga el archivo siguiente</div>
</a>
```

Pero en Wordpress me genera el siguiente HTML y queda muy feo:

```css
#dwnld-pdf {
clear: both;
padding: 0.8% 0;
display: flex;
border: 1.2px solid;
width: 232px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-evenly;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
}

#dwn-img { /* div imagen */
display: flex;
width: 28px;
}
```

```html
<a id="dwnld-pdf" class="clearfix" href="" title="Descarga el archivo archivo" download=""><p></p>
<div id="dwn-img"><img src="http://localhost/html_preg/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/adobe_pdf_document_01.gif" alt="Icono de archivo PDF"></div>
<div>Descarga el archivo siguiente</div>
</a><p><a id="dwnld-pdf" class="clearfix" href="" title="Descarga el archivo archivo" download=""></a>
</p>
```

En Vivaldi Y Google Chrome directamente no parece funcionar en el JSFIDDLE el CSS y no se visualiza bien.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que veo del código generado lo estas pegando directamente en tu post. Es por eso que añade las etiquetas `<p>` en tu codigo, yo te recomiendo agregar el link de descarga usando un filtro:

```
    add_filter('the_content', 'add_pdf_download_link');
    function add_pdf_download_link($content) {
        global $post;
        // si el tipo de post es pagina no le concatena el link
        if(get_post_type($post)=='page'){
            return $content;
        }

        $link = '<a id="dwnld-pdf" class="clearfix" href="" title="Descarga el archivo archivo" download>
<div id="dwn-img"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-basic-1/57/basic1-046_file_pdf-512.png" alt="Icono de archivo PDF"></div><div>Descarga el archivo siguiente</div>
</a>';        

        return $content.$link;
    }
```

Esto debe de ir en tu archivo functions.php de tu tema.

Comment: La solución esta bien pero si el enlace va a ser siempre el mismo al mismo PDF (o archivo que saa) y quiero que aparezca en todos los posts, pero por loq ue he veo saldria en todos los post y siempre tendria que ser el mismo enlace con el mismo texto, los cuales irian variando y no siempre habria un enlace en todos los post. Pero bueno, me guardo la solución por si acaso. Gracias.

Comment: OK en ese caso podriamos implementar otra forma de hacerlo y podriamos hacer una funcion con Shortcodes y usando extra fields de wordpress, dejame hacerlo y actualizo mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Es el tipo de caso donde un [**Shortcode**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) puede ayudar bastante. Sería el caso de simplemente poner *`[descargar-pdf]`* dentro del contenido de un post/página, y el código de shortcode se encarga de generar el HTML exacto que necesitamos.

Lo recomendado es crear un plugin pues sí cambiamos de theme el shortcode sigue funcionando. Actualmente es [prohibido publicar themes](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/handbook/review/required/#presentation-vs-functionality) en el repositorio oficial que contengan shortcodes.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: PDF Shortcode
 * Plugin URI: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/70573/238
 */

add_shortcode( 'descarga-pdf', function($atts,$content){
    # Cargar CSS propio
    // wp_enqueue_style('estilo-shortcode', plugins_url( '/css/shortcodes.css', __FILE__ ) );
    # Cargar jQuery
    // wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    $icono = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-basic-1/57/basic1-046_file_pdf-512.png';
    $url = isset( $atts['url'] ) ? $atts['url'] : 'http://example.com/documento-por-defecto.pdf';
    $texto  = isset( $atts['texto'] ) ? $atts['texto'] : 'Descarga el archivo siguiente';

    $html = sprintf(
        '<a id="dwnld-pdf" class="clearfix" href="%s" title="Descarga el archivo archivo" download>
            <div id="dwn-img"><img src="%s" alt="Icono de archivo PDF"></div><div>%s</div>
        </a>',
        $url, $icono, $texto
    );

    return $html;
});
```

En este ejemplo, sólo puede haver un shortcode por post/página, pues el *anchor* tiene un ID predefinido `id="dwnld-pdf"` (facil ajustar para una *class*).

Como hay valores predeterminados, puede ser usado en qualquier combinación:

- `[descarga-pdf]`
- `[descarga-pdf texto="Descargar acrhivo"]`
- `[descarga-pdf url="http://example.com/documento.pdf"]`